# MFC menus Open tabs dynamic menu

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am working with a MFC application, and would like to remove the dynamic entry that appears under "Arrange Icons".

I am not sure how this is added to the application, or how could I switch that off?

[image: Menu discussed (1 Home)]

Comment: You can check these two links, does it work? [mfc remove default toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720225/mfc-remove-default-toolbar), [How to hide/collapse main menu in a win32/mfc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724000/how-to-hide-collapse-main-menu-in-a-win32-mfc-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of open windows is added to the "Window" menu by the MFC framework, in the application's main window handler for the `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` command. (Actually, the framework adds the items to all menus that already contain any command with an ID between `AFX_IDM_WINDOW_FIRST` and `AFX_IDM_WINDOW_LAST` – which includes the "Cascasde," "Tile..." and "Arrange Icons" default values.)

You can remove these items by adding the `ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP()` handler to your frame window's message map and overriding that frame's [`OnInitMenuPopup()` member function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#oninitmenupopup).

Assuming your main frame is derived from the `CMDIFrameWnd` class, this override would look something like the following:

```cpp
void MyFrameWnd::OnInitMenuPopup(CMenu *pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu)
{
    CMDIFrameWnd::OnInitMenuPopup(pPopupMenu, nIndex, bSysMenu);// Call base class FIRST
    // <Insert any other code for your override>
    UINT commID = AFX_IDM_FIRST_MDICHILD; // MFC gives the first item this ID
    BOOL hadID;
    do {
        hadID = pPopupMenu->RemoveMenu(commID, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        ++commID;
    } while (hadID);
    return;
}
```

The *declaration* of the function in your class should properly have the `afx_msg` attribute, as shown below, although this is generally defined as 'nothing' in the recent MFC versions:

```cpp
class MyFrameWnd : public CMDIFrameWnd
{
    //...
protected:
    afx_msg void OnInitMenuPopup(CMenu *pPopupMenu, UINT nIndex, BOOL bSysMenu);
    //...
```

You could also reduce the removal 'loop' code to the following single line, if you prefer such compressed code:

```cpp
    for (UINT commID = AFX_IDM_FIRST_MDICHILD; Menu->RemoveMenu(commID, MF_BYCOMMAND); ++commID) ; // Empty loop
```

---

Note that this removal process will leave a 'separator' at the bottom of your application's "Window" menu; removing this as well would involve a bit more work, as that separator doesn't have a command ID – so you would need to determine its position (index) in the menu and call the `RemoveMenu()` function using that index and the `MF_BYPOSITION` flag as the second argument.

Using the code from the first snippet, and assuming that separator is at the very end of your menu, this could be achieved by adding the following code after the removal loop:

```cpp
    if (commID > AFX_IDM_FIRST_MDICHILD + 1) { // We removed at least one item, so ...
        int nItems = Menu->GetMenuItemCount(); // ... remove the separator,
        pPopupMenu->RemoveMenu(nItems - 1, MF_BYPOSITION); // assuming it's the last item!
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer @Adrian Mole - actually I got an odd issue where these automatic menus have moved from Window menu parent to the parent immediately to the left, and this has happened when I removed a parent menu that was between Window and Help. The menus are custom, (appearing the tabs that my app has opened), but I can't still see where that magic happens, and why have they shifted when I removed that parent menu, any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sergioet Are you saying you have popup menus on child windows or child tabs? If so, you can add a similar override of `OnInitMenuPopup` to the class for those windows - it's a member of the `CWnd` class, from which all (or most) other window types are derived.

Comment: sorry I've been quite busy with other things. You are right, your solution works and removes the menus. Many thanks!